# R repeat function until condition met

Tags: r, function, conditional-statements, repeat

I am trying to generate a random sample that excludes certain "bad data."  I do not know whether the data is "bad" until after I sample it.  Thus, I need to make a random draw from the population and then test it.  If the data is "good" then keep it.  If the data is "bad" then randomly draw another and test it.  I would like to do this until my sample size reaches 25.  Below is a simplified example of my attempt to write a function that does this.  Can anyone please tell me what I am missing?

```
df <- data.frame(NAME=c(rep('Frank',10),rep('Mary',10)), SCORE=rnorm(20))
df

random.sample <- function(x) {
  x <- df[sample(nrow(df), 1), ]
  if (x$SCORE > 0) return(x)
 #if (x$SCORE <= 0) run the function again
}

random.sample(df)
```

Comment: are you familiar with `?while`  ?

Comment: I took a look at ?'while' and ?Control but had trouble understanding how to use it.

Comment: So, you have to do calculation after drawing? here, you already have `SCORE`, just subset those good and sample.

Comment: @Ananta Would that be still a random sample from the original population?

Comment: @aseidlitz it's using the same info "SCORE" mentioned above unless there is something else not in the example it just reduces to a simple subsetting problem

Comment: @user1491868 well then both your data and your example are misleading...

Comment: in any case precomputed or not you can just put whatever your test is between the little square brackets then its vectorised and not looping multiple function calls.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful comments and I apologize for any confusion.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Here is a general use of a `while` loop:

```
random.sample <- function(x) {
  success <- FALSE
  while (!success) {
    # do something
    i <- sample(nrow(df), 1)
    x <- df[sample(nrow(df), 1), ]
    # check for success
    success <- x$SCORE > 0
  }
  return(x)
}
```

An alternative is to use `repeat` (syntactic sugar for `while(TRUE)`) and `break`:

```
random.sample <- function(x) {
  repeat {
    # do something
    i <- sample(nrow(df), 1)
    x <- df[sample(nrow(df), 1), ]
    # exit if the condition is met
    if (x$SCORE > 0) break
  }
  return(x)
}
```

where `break` makes you exit the `repeat` block. Alternatively, you could have `if (x$SCORE > 0) return(x)` to exit the function directly.

Answer (score 4):

use this after your first sample

```
while (any(bad <- (x$SCORE <= 0)))
   x[bad, ] <- df[sample(nrow(df), sum(bad)), ]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 random.sample <- function(x) {
   x <- df[sample(nrow(df), 1), ]
   if (x$SCORE > 0) return(x)
   Recall(x)# run the function again
 }

 random.sample(df)
#   NAME    SCORE
#14 Mary 1.252566
```

It seems to me that this should work as well:

```
 df$SCORE[ df$SCORE > 0 ][ sample(1:sum(df$SCORE > 0), 1) ]
#[1] 0.6579631
```

Comment: VERY nice help.  The Recall function is not even mentioned anywhere in all of my R manuals.  Is it better if I use: if (x$SCORE > 0) { return(x) } else { Recall(x) }?

Comment: elegant but not as efficient as a `while` loop IMHO, as it can create a large call stack.

Comment: You are essentially doing rejection sampling. It could been as simple as:  `df$SCORE[df$SCORE > 0][ sample(1:(sum(df$SCORE > 0, 1)]`. I'm not sure how to advise on the checkmark. Mine was essentially a throw-away answer. Flodel is right about efficiency. Recursion is not well supported in R.

Comment: Regarding your `df$SCORE[df$SCORE > 0][...]`, it is the same thing I commented to Stephen: OP is giving a "*simplified example*" of a more complex situation where "*I do not know whether the data is "bad" until after I sample it*". So a recursion or a while loop are about the only possible solutions.

Answer (score 3):

You can just select the rows to sample directly like so (just 5):

```
> df <- data.frame(NAME=c(rep('Frank',10),rep('Mary',10)), SCORE=rnorm(20))
> df[sample(which(df$SCORE>0), 5),]


 NAME     SCORE
14  Mary 1.0858854
10 Frank 0.7037989
16  Mary 0.7688913
5  Frank 0.2067499
17  Mary 0.4391216
```

this is without replacement, for bootstrap put in `replace=T`.

Comment: I upvoted but since the OP said *I do not know whether the data is "bad" until after I sample it* I am not sure that it will work for him. His example might have been poorly chosen.

Comment: @flodel fair enough but R is not a realtime app, nor good at recursive function calls, so if the data needs checked the test is in the data and should be vectorised and put between the brackets.. like this.

Comment: Whether I keep the observation is a function of the observation itself.  I cannot determine whether to keep the observation until after it has been drawn.

Comment: @user1491868 if the obs is really in a DF then you can do exactly that, subset by your criteria then sample...anyway it's not really that important is it :)

Comment: After thinking things through I decided to subset my data by the criteria before sampling.  But I still think this thread is useful when it is impossible to subset the data before sampling it.  Thank you to everybody for their very helpful comments and suggestions.