# Generate matrices meet conditions to obtain N matrices and rbind the N accepted matrices together

Tags: r, loops

I want to generate 400 compositional data which meet conditions and then combine them together. The means and variance correlations between three variables used to generate the data are:

```
mu <- c(45.2, 15.4, 15.4) # means
names (mu) <- c("P", "S", "Fa") # names of the three variances
sted <- c(4.830935, 3.222764, 3.222764) # standard deviations
names (sted) <- c("P", "S", "Fa") # names of the three variances

# covariance matrix: 
corMat <- matrix (c(23.337931, -7.737931, -7.737931, 
                    -7.737931, 10.386207, -5.131034,
                    -7.737931, -5.131034, 10.386207),
                  ncol = 3, byrow = T)
dimnames (corMat) <- list (row_names = c("P", "S", "Fa"),
                           col_names = c("P", "S", "Fa"))
```

The procedure of stimulated data generating includes two steps, as follows:

*Step 1:* generate a datum with a normal distribution based mean and variance correlations between three variables:

```
set.seed(1)
library(MASS)
dat1 <- mvrnorm(n = 1, mu = mu, Sigma = corMat, empirical = F)
```

*Step 2:* check if `dat1` has: `P` within the range of `45 <= P <= 55`; `S` within `12 <= S <= 22`; and `Fa` within `12 <= S <= 22`. If `dat1` meets the three conditions of `P`, `S` and `Fa`, accept `dat1`.
Repeat steps 1 and 2 until achieving `400` accepted data and `rbind` them together.

I found some questions related to `repeat + break` such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20507247/r-repeat-function-until-condition-met), but I am still stuck in  repeating *steps 1 and 2* till obtaining `400` data and bind the data together. Please can anyone help? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solves your problem. However, the generated `dat1` appears to never fulfill the conditions you want to impose. Should not `dat1` be divided by 100?

```
nSets <- 0

data <- matrix(ncol=3)

while (nSets < 400)
{
  dat1 <- mvrnorm(n = 1, mu = mu, Sigma = corMat, empirical = F)

  # dat1 <- dat1/100 <-- maybe this is necessary?

  if (dat1["P"] >= 0.45 & dat1["P"] <= 0.55 &
      dat1["S"] >= 0.12 & dat1["S"] <= 0.22 &
      dat1["Fa"] >= 0.12 & dat1["Fa"] <= 0.22)
  {
    nSets <- nSets + 1
    data <- rbind(data,dat1)
  }
}

data <-  data[-1,]
```

Comment: Hi Paul, thank you for your quick response. Yes, you are right, I forgot multiplying 100 to the conditions. I've changed them in the question body. And with the editing in your answer, it works perfectly now. Much appreciated.